# How to control the order in which repositories are looked in a repository group

Tags: nexus

How to control the order in which repositories are looked in a repository group in the "`Public Repositories-->Available Repositories`" section, the UP/DOWN arrow seems to be missing. Sometimes it seems to be going to the wrong repository and fails mentioning unable to download.

Comment: How does it matter? Why is the order important? Aren't queried artifacts supposed to be the same in each repository of the group (when they are found)?

Comment: Supposed if the 3 repositories under Available Public Repositories, unfortunately sometimes it doesn't look under artifacts of say the 3rd repository (even though the avaialble artifact is present). It just keeps saying that the artifact doesn't exist.

Comment: So I would prefer a mechanism to push the repository to the top, so that atleast it will look into the repository.

Comment: You should file a bug on the issue tracker with more details because it is definitely not the correct behaviour.

Comment: Ping... have you tried drag and drop. It should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use drag and drop to sort the repositories in the list.